# Setting up XPages Java development in a separate, modern Eclipse instance

Tags: xpages

I really miss the newer functions of a modern Eclipse implementation. Things like cool plugins such as Checkstyle, auto-javadoc, ease of JUnit testing.

I always did this whilst developing Notes Java Agents, and it was a great time saver.

I'm trying to do this with my new XPages project but I'm stumbling on how to include diverse OSGI libraries.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm DESPERTELY trying to get this exact content onto NotesIn9.  I almost have it but had some trouble getting DDE to recognize it and can't figure out the issue.  As soon as I get back to it AND figure it out I'll be posting the show.  Note: if you want to do this via DDE try this: http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/  I did get that to work but personally if I do this I want to use full Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Jesse's answer: a colleague uses Eclipse only to develop in our XPages stuff - for the Java part only. We all use a local on-disk-version of the project that can be imported into Eclipse workspace. You then can use the editors and benefits of current Eclipse versions. Caveat also: you always have to refresh/sync the sources from your on-disk-project in DDE to test. Regarding JUnit tests: we also use them and doing even automated build-tests on a Jenskins server with that method

Comment: and how do you import it? Doesn't Eclipse explode with all the native Notes elements?

Comment: Those are also just XML files. Just use "Import, Existing projects into Workspace" and you're done.

Comment: Are you working with the modern eclipse directly on the local files? Or are you creating a copy?

Comment: We are working directly in the ODP to sync everything back into the NSF (the final build also takes part in the NSF)

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to set up an Eclipse environment for XPages development is the [XPages SDK](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20SDK%20for%20Eclipse%20RCP). That should point to your Notes/Domino installations and create the Target Platform stuff for you. If you have additional libraries, you can either install them into Eclipse via the Help -> Install New Software option or add them to the Target Platform in Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform.

There's a huge caveat, though: this sort of XPages development refers to *library* development specifically, not writing XPages applications. There isn't really currently a good way to do actual-XPages dev in Eclipse without losing tooling.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. At the moment I'm just trying to develop the XPages itself, and I'm tired of Eclipse 3.4, and miss all the goodies on Eclipse Luna. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry Jesse, I've awarded the answer to Oliver since that's closer to what I want to do. Thanks for your time though.